# Silverlight DateTime formatting on Mac Problem

Tags: silverlight, macos

Here an interesting problem. If the current date is March 23, 2011 and I run the following code in my silverlight application on a Mac...

MessageBox.Show(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd, ddd dddd");

It returns: "2011-03-23, Thu Thursday" when in fact March 21 is a Wednesday! The above code works perfectly on a Windows PC.

I thought this maybe related to the computer settings on the customers Mac but they tried 3 other Macs and ddd return the next day of the week (i.e. Thu instead of Wed). Hmmm I thought, so I went out and brought a Mac Book Pro and the problem happened on that as well.

My Silverlight plug-in version on the mac is 4.0.60129.0, current culture is en-NZ, browser is Safari.

If anyone can tell me whats going on or provide a fix that would be great.

Comment: I found this link in Microsoft connect where this problem is just isolated to the New Zealand Timezone https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/588834/silverlight-date-formatting-on-mac-os-x

Comment: I ended up adding the following into my App.xaml.cs

Answer (score 0):

For a workaround I added the following code to my App.xaml.cs constructor

```
if (new DateTime(2011, 3, 28).ToString("ddd") == "Tue")
{
    CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("en-AU");

    culture.DateTimeFormat.DayNames = new[] { "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday" };
    culture.DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedDayNames = new[] { "Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat" };
    culture.DateTimeFormat.ShortestDayNames = new[] { "Su", "Mo", "Tu", "We", "Th", "Fr", "Sa" };

    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;
}
```